# CakePHP use JOIN in find method

Tags: sql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

i am newbie in cakephp and trying to implement this query

```
 SELECT DISTINCT textmessage.mobileNo FROM textmessage 
 JOIN contacts
  ON textmessage.User_id=contacts.User_id AND textmessage.mobileNo = Contacts.mobileNo
```

i am expecting only one result here .. want to implement this query in **textMessage** Controller ... i have never use join query  before in CAKEPHP... i have actually a **mobileNo** field in both the tables and i want to retrieve the mobileNo if the **mobileNo** of **textmessage** table is also in **Contacts** table

here  is what i have modified your query according to my requirments ..

```
  $this->bindModel(array('belongsTo' => array('Contact' => array('className' => 'Contact',
        'foreignKey' => false,
        'conditions' => array('Message.user_id = Contact.user_id','Message.mobileNo =  Contact.mobileNo')))), true);

  return  $message_details = $this->find('all', array('conditions' => array(),
        'fields' => array('DISTINCT mobileNo')));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the following code in your controller's code:

If you need only single record:

```
function test1()
{
$this->TextMessage->bindModel(array('belongsTo' => array('Contact' => array('className' => 'Contact',
                                        'foreignKey' => false,
                                        'conditions' => array('TextMessage.user_id = Contact.user_id')))), false);
$message_details = $this->TextMessage->find('all', array('conditions' => array(),
                                             'fields' => array('DISTINCT mobileNo')));

}
```

If you have multiple text messages corresponding to each contact then try the following:

```
function test2()
{
$this->Contact->bindModel(array('hasMany' => array('TextMessage' => array('className' => 'TextMessage',
                                      'foreignKey' => false,
                                      'conditions' => array('TextMessage.user_id = Contact.user_id'),
                                      'fields' => array('DISTINCT mobileNo')))
                    ), false);
$message_details = $this->Contact->find('all', array('conditions' => array()));                   
}
```

You can also write the association in your model. I gave you an example to dynamically join any table on the fly.

According to your edited question, if you don't need two arrays. Use [query()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-query) function.

Hope this will fulfill your requirement.

Comment: @Arjun Jain thanks Arjun .. but you  didnt use "distinct" in ur query?

Comment: and also when i run your first query ..it isnt giving me the required result.

Comment: where i am getting the mobileNo in your query also no distinct use ?

Comment: I edited my answer. During defining association you can use `fields` option and provide all fields you need. `DISTINCT` keyword has to use before the required field name.

Comment: well the first think i am not getting the required result ... because what i want is i want a single coulmn data .. i dont want an array ... just a single field data ... it is returing me 2 arrays ... one is contact array and other is Messages array ... i m giving you the working sql which is right now giving me only one column data ..so i want the exact copy in Cake

Comment: You can either use `list` instead of `all` or `first`. The CakePHP offers you the result in an array.

Comment: but why it is returning me the two tables in an array  ... i just want the column data which is common in both the tables ..it is returning me one array with empty data and other Message array which some data

Comment: Whenever you define an association in models you will always get associated arrays that are bind. It is the only way to handle it. If you need only some columns as result, then specify those in `fields` option.

Comment: okk .. but when i try your edited answer ... in which you have added the field option then it gives me an sql syntax error .. i can show you the error as well if you ask

Comment: Count the number of brackets you entered.

Comment: well finally i resolved the error but why query  isn't checking the condition ... giving me all the phone numbers ... i have actually modified your query... i am putting the query in my question ..

Comment: well sir it hasn't  solved yet .. i have updated my question ... the result is showing me all the numbers .. it isn't checking the numbers into other table .. in short the condition is not working .. i am trying to

Comment: well the problem is almost solved ... but just one thing i want to ask ... your query is doing "LEFT JOIN" .. but i want to just "JOIN" the table

Comment: Use this link to make a `join` instead: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables